# Помогите распарсить профиль в board в VkApi

Tags: java, android, android-vksdk

Помогите распарсить  профиль в board в VkApi....не понимаю как...все приходит, правильно, а фото и имя с фамилией стоит одна у всех... как это исправить?

```
VKParameters param = new VKParameters();
param.put(VKApiConst.GROUP_ID, "ID_ГРУППЫ");
param.put("topic_id", "ID_ТОПИКА");
param.put(VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1);

VKRequest result =
        new VKRequest(String.format(Locale.US, "%s.%s", "board", "getComments"),
                param, VKCommentArray.class);
result.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);
        VKCommentArray parsedModel = (VKCommentArray) response.parsedModel;
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(response.responseString);
            responseObject = object.getJSONObject("response");
            array = responseObject.getJSONArray("profiles");
            for (int i = 0; i < object.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = array.getJSONObject(i);
                first_name = item.getString("first_name");
                last_name = item.getString("last_name");
                logo = item.getInt("photo_50");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiComment topic : parsedModel) {

            String date = (new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy 'в' HH:mm",
                    new Locale("ru")).format(new Date(topic.date * 1000L)));
            arr_list.add(new BoardItems1(logo, first_name + " " + last_name, date,
                    topic.text));
        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ошибка такая:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>   atcalculation.***.**.**.by.board.BoardActivity1$1.onComplete(BoardActivity1.java:147)
>   at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest$3.run(VKRequest.java:482)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)

Comment: Вы пробовали взять `Gson` и распарсить приходящий в ответе `JSON`? Либа не обновлялась полтора года и некоторые вещи там точно не реализованы. Например нет отметок того, что пост суть реклама. Их можно получить только руками разбирая JSON. Нельзя получить эти данные иначе. Скорее всего ваш случай - аналогичен. Т.е. иного ответа вы не получите.

Comment: можно чуть чуть показать как это вытянуть и подключить?

Comment: Тут, на сайте, множество примеров. В сети их тоже много. Могу, например, ссылку на доку дать: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться

Comment: Начал парсить...получилось, но фото и имя с фамилией стоит одна и у всех.....помогите исправить....пост обновил

Comment: Вы каждую итерацию цикла перезаписываете значение одних и тех же переменных. Вмесо этого создайте по `ArrayList<String>` для имени, фамилии и фотки и в них добавляйте эти значения.

Comment: Ну я создал для имени и фамилии ArrayList<String> и для фото ArrayList<Integer>.....а куда их добавлять для отображения?

Comment: Собственно наполняете эти списки в одном цикле, и вытаскиваете по индексу в другом.

Comment: Вытаскивать по индексу в другом? Это где? Я очень туплю....помогите плз, тыкните пальцем

Comment: Смотрите обновление ответа. И старайтесь придумывать заголовки ответов без слова `помогите`

Answer (score 5):

Согласно [доке](https://vk.com/dev.php?method=board.getComments) вам надо добавить к запросу параметр `extended` со значением `1`, для того, чтобы информация о юзерах приходила вместе с информацией о комментарии.

После этого, согласно той же доке информация о юзерах, будет в массиве, лежащем рядом с массивом комментов.

---

```
VKParameters param = new VKParameters();
param.put(VKApiConst.GROUP_ID, "ID_ГРУППЫ");
param.put("topic_id", "ID_ТОПИКА");
param.put(VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1);

VKRequest result = new VKRequest(String.format(Locale.US, "%s.%s", "board", "getComments"), param, VKCommentArray.class);
result.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);
        VKCommentArray parsedModel = (VKCommentArray)response.parsedModel;
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> surNames = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> logos = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(response.responseString);
            responseObject = object.getJSONObject("response");
            array = responseObject.getJSONArray("profiles");
            for (int i=0; i< object.length(); i++){
                JSONObject item = array.getJSONObject(i);
                names.add(item.getString("first_name"));
                surNames.add(item.getString("last_name"));
                logos.add(item.getInt("photo_50"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiComment topic : parsedModel) {
            String date = (new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy 'в' HH:mm", new Locale("ru")).format(new Date(topic.date* 1000L)));
            arr_list.add(new BoardItems1(logos.get(i), names.get(i) + " " + surNames.get(i), date, topic.text));
            i++
        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: В том то и прикол что кроме иформации о комментариях больше ничего не приходит

Comment: @sviter-pro, покажите какой вам именно JSON приходит - его можно из `VKResponse response` как-то вытащить. И покажите как вы пытаетесь получить массив юзеров из `response`. Возможно это надо вручную сделать и в самом SDK такой возможности нет.

Comment: Юзеры должны быть в массиве `profiles`. Возможно, также, проблема в том, что вы не указали версию апи. Или к запросу токен не придан.

Comment: Ответ обновил.....в response приходит все, а в parseModel не все

Comment: @sviter-pro, значит надо вручную парсить. Возьмите либу GSON и вручную из Json получите список юзеров

Comment: Ошибку выбивает на arr_list.add();

Comment: @sviter-pro, ваше сообщение очень неинформативно. Надо указывать какая ошибка. Я просто скопировал ваш код и немного его дополнил.

Comment: ошибку добавил! пост обновил!

Comment: @sviter-pro, этого недостаточно. Укажите на какой именно строке падает. Какая строка - 147 в BoardActivity1?

Comment: arr_list.add(new BoardItems1(logos.get(i), names.get(i) + " " + surNames.get(i), date, topic.text));

Comment: @sviter-pro, значит что-то из logos, names или surNames парсится не правильно или там данных нет, т.к. список/списки пустые - проверьте какой именно пуст.